# Solving higher order pdes

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

So here's my problem, while you solve the Euler Bernoulli beam Equation by separation of variables, how do I have to prove the separated function of  space  are orthogonal? If so, are hyperbolic sines and cosines orthogonal when you have a product or a linear combination of them?

The pde is- $u_{tt}+\alpha^{2} u_{xxxx} = o$ where $\alpha$ is a constant that is material dependent. The separated function of space is $F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} [cosh(\beta_{n}x)-cos(\beta_{n}x)]-[sinh(\beta_{n}x)-sin(\beta_{n}x)]$ where $\beta_{n}$ is some constant. Boundary conditions are $u(0,t) = 0, u'(o,t) =0, u''(L,t) = 0, u'''(L,t) = 0$

followed by the initial conditions,
$u(x,0) = h(x)$ the initial profile of the beam
$u'(x,0) = g(x)$ the initial velocity with which the beam bends.

Comment: This is probably better suited to physics.stackexchange.

Comment: Still unclear. Eigenvalues can't be orthogonal. Orthogonality depends on boundary conditions. What is the equation anyway. Etc.

Comment: The equation is u_(tt) + a*u_(xxxx) =0, where a is a constant that is material dependent.

Comment: I hope that edit makes more sense.